# Como crear una capa de virtualización de Servicios

Tags: .net, visual-studio, webservice

Alguien me podría ayudar a crear una capa de virtualización de servicios, esta capa de virtualización deberá servir para que los clientes no consumirán directamente los servicios expuestos por los proveedores, proporcionando agilidad para poder realizar transformaciones, orquestaciones, cambio en interfaces y desacoplamiento entre los servicios expuestos y/o los servicios consumidores.

Saludos.

Comment: ayudar o hacer? Esta web no es para que nadie haga las tareas de nadie, sino para ayudar a desencallar aquellos puntos en que no se sabe como avanzar. Podrías colgar el código de lo que llevas hecho hasta el momento?

Comment: Jajajaja pos no quiero que me pasen una solución lista para entregar, mmmm simplemente tal vez una ayuda como "podrias leer sobre tal framework", "deberias partir por tal lugar", no se cosas por el estilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que planteas suena a [BizTalk](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_BizTalk_Server) service

con este podrias crear servicio que mapeen con servicios o librerias de terceros, entonces el cliente consume los servicios que BizTalk exponga abstrayendo de la libreria de lso proveedores. Por supuesto la idea es que no tengas que desarrollar los servicios intermedio entre el cliente y el proveedor, sino que los configuras

Esto tambien se podria implementar en Azure

Answer (score 1):

Una opción para lo que necesitas es implementar un REST API como facade para los servicios que requieres virtualizar.
Realmente depende mucho de la arquitectura de tus servicios, si todo esta en .NET deberias checar https://servicestack.net/.

Comment: La idea es consumir n servicios en diferentes tecnologias con diferentes formatos, y luego el bus deberia estandariza a un formato unico.